# Joomla 403 redirect code

Tags: php, .htaccess, joomla

I have a problem with getting Joomla 3 to redirect users to a member page when a `403` is detected.

Upon researching and trying various things for literally days now I've finally given in to having to ask the question.

From my research I understand that the Joomla reads from the `templates/system/error.php` master file.

I have the following code implemented within the `error.php` and I have tried forcing it through `.htaccess` as well and neither work.

```
$ReferTo = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$ReferTo = base64_encode($ReferTo);

if ($this->error->getCode() == '403') {
header('Location: ' . $this->baseurl . '/members'); die();
}
```

The current behaviour is Joomla just sends the user to a very unhelpful `403` default page.

Any ideas on this one? Thanks so much for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fortunately I have managed to find a solution by fluke. I dropped the system folder error.php file into all the individual template folders to create a system override. So far Joomla has recognised this.

Answer (score 0):

Create under the main directory of your Joomla website, a 403.html file with the following content:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://www.yourwebsite.com/members" />
```

In your .htaccess file, add the following code:

```
ErrorDocument 403 /403.html
```

If you only want to do that for certain requests, then redirect to a 403.php file in your .htaccess file (instead of redirecting to 403.html file), check the REQUEST URI to see if it is indeed coming from the members area, and then redirect back to the members page.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Unfortunately Joomla still decided to overrule the HTACCESS and continue to redirect to it's own 403 page.

Fortunately I have managed to find a solution by fluke. I dropped the system folder error.php file into all the individual template folders to create a system override. So far Joomla has recognised this.

Answer (score 0):

Joomla creates/raises a 403 event, when trying to access a protected article. So editing the file System / error.php or within the template itself did not work. Also the other solutions in .htaccess or httpd.conf using ErrorDocument did not work.

I also tried the code this-> error-> getCode () == '403', but it doesn't fire.

The only solution I found was to modify the HTML view for the articles to redirect to an article where I show a login and a personalized message.

The file to modify is components / com_content / views / article / view.html.php line 134 to 139

Joomla 3.9.20

The code to replace is the following:

```
 // Check the view access to the article (the model has already computed the values).
                if ($ item-> params-> get ('access-view') == false && ($ item-> params-> get ('show_noauth', '0') == '0'))
                {
                        $ app-> enqueueMessage (JText :: _ ('JERROR_ALERTNOAUTHOR'), 'error');
                        $ app-> setHeader ('status', 403, true);
                        return;                        
                }
```

For this

```
                // Check the view access to the article (the model has already computed the values).
                if ($item->params->get('access-view') == false && ($item->params->get('show_noauth', '0') == '0'))
                {
                        header('Location:https://www.yourwebpage/withLoginandCustomMessage.php');
                 die();
                }
```

This will only be shown to users trying to view articles that require registration or with other ACLs.

I am aware that we should not edit the files since in a Joomla update, these changes could be lost, but it was the only solution I found (neither modules or plugins covered this problem and apparently it is something that is brought from joomla 1.5).

Comment: If you are not sure how to modify your Joomla application without hacking core file, you might like to ask on [joomla.se] Stack Exchange if anyone can help you to execute this technique in a more stable way.